# WebView вытесняет остальные элементы с экрана

Tags: android, xml, webview

Делаю `WebView` и кнопки, которые должны находиться внизу.

Нужно,чтобы кнопки были под `WebView` и не закрывали элементы страницы. Но что-то не так, как надо. Кнопки вообще исчезли с экрана.
(Код написать не могу).

Так выглядит XML разметка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: Очень интересно][image: Очень интересно]

Comment: А почему не задать фиксированную высоту вебвью?

Comment: А не надо будет устанавливать разную высоту для разных экранов?

Comment: Так высоту екрана можно вычислить програмно и от нее уже минусовать высоту кнопок если она фиксирована должна быть. Или в XML указать соотношение высоты кнопок к высоте вебвью.

Comment: К сожалению я не такой кулхацкер. Я человек простой

Comment: Никто с клавой в руках не родился. Чтение и кодинг - вот что нужно!

Comment: код нужно размещать в виде текста, в специальных тегах, а не скриншотами. Писать надо строго по проблеме, о своих личных переживаниях и сомнениях пишите в личный дневничек, тогда минусов будет намного меньше

Comment: Пишу с тегами, но оно все-равно пишет, что надо в теги

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так высоту екрана можно вычислить програмно и от нее уже минусовать высоту кнопок если она фиксирована должна быть. Или в `XML` указать соотношение высоты кнопок к высоте `WebView`.

Пример второго варианта:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <WebView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.9"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: В дочерние LinearLayout-ты заливаете Ваши вебвью и кнопки. И LinearLayout добавляете android:layout_weight="X". Вместо Х естественно ставите значение соотношения.

Comment: заворачивать один виджет в контейнер — дурной тон, сами виджеты имеют такие же атрибуты (в частности вес), а потом жалуются, что андроид тормозной и фризы

Comment: Согласен, абсолютно. потому первый раз так и написал. Потом, глядя на обилие баттонов в коде автора - все же решил чтобы не получилось так, что будет изменен атрибут в вебвью и потом в каждой кнопке - лучше уж сразу показать какая структура должна быть.